# WooCommerce Cart Product of Qty and ACF Value, issue with Variables

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get the Product for the values from `$cart_item['quantity']` and `get_field('box_sqft')`

My attempt is to display the total square feet of a product based on the quantity in the quantity box.

Each product has Custom Field that contains the square feet value.

```php
<?php

$sqft = get_field('box_sqft');
$qty =  $cart_item['quantity'];

$total = $qty * $sqft;

echo $total;

?>
```

I think the solution has something to do with `$_POST` but am not 100% sure.

Comment: I think I found the issue and solution, but I would be very interested in seeing everyone's input on this.

Comment: When iterating through cart items with `foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){` you will use `$sqft = get_field('box_sqft', $cart_item['product_id']);` or `$sqft = get_field('box_sqft', $cart_item['data']->get_id());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution was:

```php
$sqft = get_field('box_sqft', $product_id);
$qty =  $cart_item['quantity'];
echo ($qty * $sqft);
```

@LoicTheAztec Thank you very much for your help, but I do not see a reason to explore your solution.